# Finding the max element in a stack

Tags: c++

I have my first assignment using a Stack Class that uses a dynamically allocated array to store data values, and I am confused trying to find the max and min elements of the stack. I was given the header file for the class Stack, which has the functions, Empty, Full, Top, Push, Pop, Size, Max, Min, and Peek. Can I have some advice on how to properly get the Max of a stack?

Here is what I have so far:

```
int Stack :: Max(){

    if (Empty()){
        throw EmptyStack();
    }
    int max = array[top];
    int next;

    while (!Empty()){
        next = array[top];
    }
    if (max < next){
        max = next;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Was there a particular problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: It seems your stack is basically an array. Forget about stacks for a minute how would you find the maximum value in an array? That's all you need to do here.

Comment: You don't specify what the primitive functions are doing. In particular, what are Min, Max and Peek ?

Comment: Your question does not seem to be asking to implement the class, but to use it. So this code is useless.

Comment: Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]. When you're struggling with that task, describe how you would do it independently of any language.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop runs endlessly, as it never removes elements from the `array` to cause the `!Empty()` condition to ever evaluate as `false`.  And, it doesn't modify `top`, so it is always evaluating the same element over and over.

Since you clearly have direct access to the `array`, just iterate through it normally. Try something more like this instead (assuming the stack indexes the `array` elements from `top` down to 0):

```
int Stack :: Max(){

    if (Empty()){
        throw EmptyStack();
    }

    int max = array[top];

    for (int i = top-1; i >= 0; --i){
        int next = array[i];
        if (next > max){
            max = next;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

And then you can do the same thing for `Min()`, just using `if (next < min)` instead.